# How to Render Component in server/api?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Working on a Nuxt 3 project to embed a form on a third party website,
the logic is like this:

- lets say [example.app](https://example.app/) is a Nuxt 3 project connected to a supabase databse with a table "**Projects**"
- on [anotherwebsite.com](https://anotherwebsite.com/) we want to put an iframe with the source of "[example.com/api/project/](https://example.com/api/project/PROJECT_UUID)**[PROJECT_UUID](https://example.com/api/project/PROJECT_UUID)**"
now we need to have that api endpoint output the HTML of a simple contact form.

The form is actually a simple component **FormComponent.vue** that on submit creates a new entry in supabase for table "**Submissions**"
Is there a way to render the **FormComponent.vue** when accessing the api url: "[example.com/api/project/](https://example.com/api/project/PROJECT_UUID)**[PROJECT_UUID](https://example.com/api/project/PROJECT_UUID)**" ?

Example:

File : `api/project.ts`

```
export default defineEventHandler(() => {
  let html = '<div>
    <button>Hello World</button>
  </div>'
  return html;
});
```

now if we access the example.app/api/231-2312-123-123
will return the rendered html like this:
[image: hello world]

#### So what I need is to do something like this:

```
import FormComponent from "component/location/form.vue";
import compile_function from 'somewhere'?
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const id = getRouterParam(event, 'id')
  
  let html = compile_function( FormComponent, {project_id:id} );

  return html;
});
```

#### Next project Example

Basically,
Trying to do something similar to Feedbase :

- https://www.feedbase.co/widget/e03305e8-c822-4222-9c5e-f53a47d0a5ee
- https://codepen.io/perlatsp/pen/eYxeYmX
  Feedbase seems to be built with NextJS

#### Vue-Email

I've found this module for nuxtjs vue-email that works in the same principle,
https://github.com/Dave136/vue-email:

https://github.com/Dave136/vue-email/blob/main/packages/compiler/src/template.ts

but feeling kind of lost on this code.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the problem? Generally that's what you'd get with a nuxt page

Comment: @EstusFlask I've updated the question with more context and examples.